# Why does twitter api limit prevents me from seeing tweets on other sites?

Tags: twitter, rate-limiting

I am using this library http://lab.rog.ie/chirp/ and when I'm connected to my account I can't load anyone's stream.
This is the response:

```
Failed to load resource
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/elektronaut.json?count=10&callback=jQuery180016162077663466334_1347353152273&_=1347353152291
```

Is it because the api request limit? I red the section about request limit https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting but I still don't understand what is happening...

Comment: Even on the site you gave, the example seems to not be working

Comment: does it give you `Couldn't get these tweets :(`? because as I said, it happens to me only in Chrome, in FF I get the tweets

Comment: Also, I tried a different library and I get the same error in the console

Comment: It didn't work on Chrome but it's back working now. I don't know if they changed something...

Comment: @Double the limit is hourly, what I don't understand is what's draining it...

Comment: The number of requests per hour is quite high. A [guy](https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet/issues/258) had a similar issue caused by a Chrome plugin

Comment: Huh... tahnx, apparently it was a track-blocking addon for chrome `Do Not Track Plus`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be caused by the Chrome addon **Do No Track Plus** as said [here](https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet/issues/258).